# Как реализовать авторизацию Vue + Php

Tags: php, vue.js

У меня есть приложение написано на Vue.js + php. Я не знаю способ, который помог бы организовать авторизацию пользователя, чтобы потом на странице я могу увидеть свои данные. Есть способ это организовать без сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас стек vue+php то vue общается с php через api запросы.

1. У вас должна быть форма на Vue с логином и паролем, при отправке которой происходит POST запрос к PHP на авторизацию.
2. Со стороны сервера должна быть БД пользователей с полями: логин, хэш пароля, ключ сессии, дата входа (или срок жизни, как хотите).

> Если хотите ходить с нескольких устройств, уместно таблицу пользователей и сессий разделить на две отдельные и класть туда еще ip, useragent и прочие полезные вещи, которые позволят повысить безопасность.

При запросе на авторизацию на сервере проверяем логин и пароль по базе, если такие есть, генерируем ключ сессии, пишем его в базу вместе с датой входа (или сроком жизни) и отдаем этот ключ обратно в Vue в ответе на запрос.

> В качестве сессионного ключа можно использовать хэш (например sha256) от логина, метки времени и какой-нибудь соли.

На стороне Vue запоминаем полученный ключ и добавляем его в заголовок **всех остальных** запросов к серверу по которым будем получать персонализированные пользовательские данные.

Во всех остальных запросах на стороне сервера, **перед тем** как выполнить сам запрос, ищем ключ в БД. Если нашли и дата не истекла, возвращаем ответ на запрос (с учетом того пользователя, которому принадлежит ключ). В противном случае возвращаем заголовок 401 (Unauthorized) который скажет Vue о том, что авторизация протухла/недействительна и надо снова показывать форму входа.

> Частой практикой является делать периодические фоновые запросы на сервер на предмет того, не истекла ли авторизация и если да, то разлогинить пользователя на клиенте.

Совсем по-хорошему все запросы между клиентом и сервером должны быть подписаны на [JWT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) но вы вряд-ли обойдетесь без сторонних библиотек ([js](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) [php](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)) для его реализации.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Ну к сожалению у нас на дем. экзамене можно использовать только то, что дадут.

Comment: Если на экзамене - то просто запрос и проверка на наличие Юзер/Пароль в базе (может быть просто текстовым файлом) и отдать Vue - true, и дальше пустить к Главному компоненту после компонента Login.